# How to provide file path in cucumber feature file table

Tags: selenium, automation, cucumber, cucumber-java

I am trying to automate uploading picture with different file formats in the same cucumber scenario. can i provide the picture paths in  tables? For eg :

```
Scenario Outline: Upload picture with diff types    
 Given i upload the file type <picturePath> 
 Examples: 
  | /src/test/pic.jpeg   | 
  | /src/test/pic.mpeg   |
```

Answer (score 2):

Try `Given i upload the file type "<picturePath>"` so it's parsed as a string. Also the table should look like:

```
Examples:
  | picturePath        |
  | /src/test/pic.jpeg |
  | /src/test/pic.mpeg |
```